# How to access/manage Actions on Google project via api

Tags: actions-on-google

I have some actions on google projects. I can modify them via the web console and the `gactions` CLI tool. But I found no resource on how to manage (list/modify/update) action projects via an API? Is this not possible?

I've found a service named [Voiceflow](https://www.voiceflow.com/), which is a tool for creating Alexa skills and Google Actions using a graphical UI. It requires users to authorize their Google account in order to access their Google Actions. Which API are they using? I've looked into [Google's API Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) but found no similar API. But as they are using some API, I suppose it's possible to manage one's Google Actions via API. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

---

EDIT: I have done some digging and found that I can request permission to access Actions using this url as OAuth scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.builder). But I found no docs on how to actually view/edit the Actions.

Moreover, I've found another resource named [Actions API](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/actions.googleapis.com). It's description says `Google Actions API allows developer to register and manage their actions on Google Cloud Platform.` But I see no guide on how to use it.

Comment: `gactions` is the best way to manage AoG projects from the command line.

Comment: I use `gactions` but it's primarily for the `update` operation. I did some digging and it's using the `actions.builder` scope for it's operation. But I found no documentation on what other things are possible via this API. Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: That API does not have any public documentation.

Comment: Thats a shame. You're a member on the Google Action GitHub organization. So you obviously know a lot about this. Can you give some advice on how to do it programmatically? Any resource to follow would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: The best option is to use the `gactions` interface, and some things may not be progammatically possible.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to settle for this. The gactions interface is pretty limited in its capabilities. Would it get some more features in future? It would be great to be able to automate the process